# Running console applications from a WCF service - where to host it?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-7.5, quartz.net

Currently working on a .NET solution for an application server. I'm using .NET 4.0 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.

My requirements are:

- The application server can run multiple Console applications at once on a schedule - Quartz.net looks like a really good solution to this problem - and is working well for me so far
- The application server will also host a web application that will report on jobs (what time they ran, what they did, how long they took etc)
- I would like to be able to restart the "service" that is running my jobs and trigger ad hoc jobs from the web interface.
- The Service that is running my jobs needs to run all the time
- Once this is live I will not have direct access to the machine to restart a Windows Service, but i could potentially setup IIS to be able to do this for me.

WCF Services looks quite promising to me - but I'm not sure where to host it. My current project uses a WCF Service to run console applications using the Quartz.net plugin. Configuration for what to run and when to run it is stored in an oracle database and my WCF service connets directly to the database to retrieve this information (not sure if that is the intended use of WCF).

If I host the WCF Service in IIS / WAS then running the console applications might be a security concern from what I've read. I can keep the WCF service running all the time using appFabric at least. Alternatively I could host it in a Windows Service and allow my web app to consume the WCF service to report on the jobs. I'm concerned about using a Windows Service though as I wont have direct maintenance access to this machine and if it breaks I'm in trouble. I would really like to be able to do the maintenance from a web application. A windows service also feel a little unnecessary given it can be hosted from IIS.

So my question is - is a WCF Service the right approach to this problem or can anyone think of a better approach?

If a WCF service is a good approach - where should I host it so that I can perform maintenance via a web interface given I will not have direct access to the machine itself?

Should the WCF service be the one to start and schedule the jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overengineering it, possibly.

The Problem: You have a web site which needs to start up jobs on an ad-hoc basis. Other jobs will be run to a fixed schedule. The web site will report on all/any of these jobs.

For running the scheduled jobs, a Windows Service using Quartz is indeed an ideal solution for the fixed schedule part. However, to report on those jobs the data must be collected by the Service and made available. A service can be set up to restart on fail, so you can guarantee that it will always be running (barring a minute or two when it's restarting if it fails - and why should it?. However, any history will be lost unless the Service stores it somewhere it can be retrieve it after a restart.

The simpler solution to the web site getting the history is for the Service to write its data to a database. Then it doesn't worry about a restart: all the history has already been saved, and the data can be read by the web site at any time.

Similarly, if the web site talks directly to the Service (as a WCF Service or otherwise) then what happens if the service is not currently running? The request gets fails until the restart is completed. Frustrating for the user. Alternatively, the web site puts the request into the database. The service monitors the database for requests, and starts jobs appropriately when it sees a new request. If a request is written while the service is not running, when it restarts it will see the request(s) in the DB and execute them.

So I think using a WCF service is overkill, and actually introduces some problems: persistence of history, and what to do about requests made while the service is down. These problems don't arise if you go the way I've described.

Cheers -

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think you're right. I'm a bit disappointed though because I was really looking forward to designing something really cool... Now it's so functional and bland